# JAVA : Clarifications for Creating objects

Tags: java, oop, object

I am newbie for the Java and currently learning java based on the oracle java tutorial as link below :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html

```
public class Rectangle {
public int width = 0;
public int height = 0;
public Point origin;

// four constructors
public Rectangle() {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
}
public Rectangle(Point p) {
    origin = p;
}
public Rectangle(int w, int h) {
    origin = new Point(0, 0);
    width = w;
    height = h;
}
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
    origin = p;
    width = w;
    height = h;
}

// a method for moving the rectangle
public void move(int x, int y) {
    origin.x = x;
    origin.y = y;
}

// a method for computing the area of the rectangle
public int getArea() {
    return width * height;
}
}
```

Based on the code above, it was stated in the web as below:

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
```

This calls one of Rectangle's constructors that initializes origin to originOne. Also, the constructor sets width to 100 and height to 200. Now there are two references to the same Point object—an object can have multiple references to it, as shown in the figure:

[image]

My Question is , is the image above represent the code correctly?  I
believe the origin and origineOne should be vice-versa in the diagram since it initializes origin to originOne. Correct me if i am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes , the image represents the code correctly.we can have any number of references pointing to the same Object.
Taking the image into account [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wdrMD.gif
there is Point Object which is initialized as x=23, y=94.
Basically "Point" is a class .
During initialization

```
Point originOne =  new Point(23,94);
```

An object of Point class is created in your java's JVM which takes up particular amount of Memory.the Object reference "originOne"  contains memory address of Object "Point"

To refer to this memory location we use "object references" which in this case is originOne. so, we can have any number of references.

```
Rectangle rectOne = new Rectangle(originOne, 100, 200);
```

this calls the following constructor

```
public Rectangle(Point p, int w, int h) {
origin = p;
width = w;
height = h;
}
```

now "originOne's" value is copied to  rectangle's variable "origin" .
thus origin now becomes object Reference of object Point.

they refer to the same object (same memory address) where x=23, y=94

try printing object reference it will give you:-
Proper classname@hexadecimal hashcode of memory location

For better understanding assume an 
1>Object to be Human 
2>object Reference to a name .

Let human's name be Alan officially and his pet name be paul . 
but paul or Alan it still refers to same Human Being.

i hope you understood it now.

Comment: Thanks Prashast 
To summarize , can i conclude the rectone is a new rectangle object contain width 100 ,height 200, x=23 and y=94 ?

Comment: rectOne is a new rectangle object with width=100, height=200 origin.x=23; origin.y=94 .Rectangle has Point object origin thus it would be origin.x & origin.y.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, Yes. So,

If you do

```
originOne.setLocation(0,0);
```

This will reflect in `origin` in `rectOne` as `origin` is referring to same location in heap as `originOne`

And if you do

```
originOne = new Point(0,0);
```

You have disconnected `originOne` from previous reference, but `rectOne`'s `origin` will continue to point to previous reference, which is Point[x=23,y=94].